# How to override api controller in Opencart 3?

Tags: api, overriding, opencart

Probably it is a simple question but I stuck here. I need to override some functions in Opencart 3.0.3 API. For example, /catalog/controller/api/login.php.

I installed Override Engine 6.5.15.
I put the file login.php into folder /system/library/override/api/catalog/controller/api/login.php

```
class api_ControllerApiLogin extends ControllerApiLogin {
    public function index() {
        // new code - nothing happens
    }
}
```

And when I call the API login method - this file doesn't work. It calls a method from /catalog/controller/api/login.php.

Can someone help me to handle with this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: First of all, show the way you are calling API. Secondly - why don't you just put it in /catalog/controller/api/login.php?

Comment: I'm calling using curl and a link http://opencart.silver-solutions.com.ua/index.php?route=api/login
/catalog/controller/api/login.php - my changes can be rewritten after opencart updates, right?